# For loop in python (Simple)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, indexing, iteration

I have a really really simple question that I struggle with :)

I need to iterate over list of truples in means of lower triangle matrix in python

---

**python code**

```
dataset = #list of truples

for i, left in enumerate(dataset):
  for j, right in enumerate(dataset):
    if j <= i : continue    #fixme there should be a better way
    foo(left,right)
```

**target pseudo code**

```
for( i=0; i<size; i++ )
  for( j=i; j<size; j++ )
    foo(data[i],data[j])
```

---

Thank you very very much :)

Comment: Your target pseudo code looks very "C like".

Comment: I'm a "language surfer" and yup many times I use C and Java. So my notion of "pseudo coding" is bias. Thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the pseudo code this should be something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):   
  for j in range(i, len(data)):
    foo(data[i],data[j])
```

also u can do it with one liner:

```
[foo(data[i],data[j]) for i in range(0, len(data)) for j in range(i, len(data)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html).

```
import itertools

for (left,right) in itertools.combinations(data,2):
    foo(left,right)
```